# MS Dynamics slow response when inserting lead record from WSDL

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-crm

My client uses Microsoft Dynamics CRM. We wrote a basic php try catch script to post a forms values to their CRM.

While testing the first submission takes a few seconds to get a response from the server. All others are returned very quickly. My client mentioned this isn't our code that MS Dynamics hangs up sometimes almost like when an office app has to load for the first time.

I'm not familiar with Dynamics, does the server go to sleep or slow down if not in use? Is there anyway to keep it in whatever state it's in when it responds immediately?

All I can think of is to set a cronjob and ping it every few minutes or hours to keep the server active and responding. Anyone have some info on what could be causing the initial delay? And if this is the wrong site please migrate.

Comment: Random wild guess: Reverse DNS lookup of your IP -> hostname that gets cached so it only happens on the first request.

Comment: @DerfK I forgot to mention the current CRM server is on an internal server / IP. The form posts to a public IP where the submission is then routed through the firewall to CRM server on local network.